# pipreqs has the unicode Error under a virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I tried to use `pipeqs` to generate **requirements.txt** in a virtual environment (`virtualenv`).

*However, I got an error as follows:*

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 184:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

*Then I tried:*

```
pipreqs --encoding=utf-8
```

*And still got the error saying:*

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 64:
invalid start byte
```

Not sure anyone knows how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I got exactly same error. Reading Theo answer, I figured workaround in venv

```
pipreqs --ignore bin,etc,include,lib,lib64
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```sh
pipreqs --encoding=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: what sorcery is this  can you link us some documentation on this working piece.  THanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had to run the following command to ignore the virtual environment directory:

```
pipreqs --ignore <env_dir>
```

In my case I ran: `pipreqs --ignore .env`

Answer (score 1):

Pipreqs only uses a unique encoding for all files, so specifying a specific encoding won't solve all problems (see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/214): there is no dynamic determination of encodings in the library as of today).

Thus, using `pipreqs --encoding=iso-8859-1` might solve your problem, but it could also cause crashes on other modules containing non iso-8859-1 files (in my case, `ast` package).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no clean solution for this, but a dirty workaround can be to temporarily comment the faulty import in the source code.